# Programmatically Attach PDF from MemoryStream to Outlook E-Mail Items

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf, outlook, memorystream

Would it be possible to attach PDF from **MemoryStream** or other **functions** to Outlook E-Mail Items **MailItem.Attachment.add()**, rather than from the file on the hard disk by passing the physical path of file in this method.

I would like to create the Outlook mailitem for the users with the PDF attached programmatically, and let the users to review and send out the email by themselves.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it like you wanted to include the PDF in the email instead of attaching it as an attachment??

Comment: Hi, Mohit Shrivastava.

Actually, I have generated an PDF by using Reporting Services, and then I put it into the Memory Stream. 

What I want to do is to put this file from the memory stream as an attachment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using the Outlook Object Model - [Attachments.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) will only let you pass a file name for the `olByValue` attachments. [Extended MAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815424.aspx) (C++ or Delphi) only operates on IStream objects (`IAttach::OpenProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN, IID_IStream,...)`), [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) lets you pass file name, url, array, IStream or IStorage to [RDOAttachments.Add](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachments.htm).

Comment: Convert you data to an array of byte, pass it to RDOMail.Attachments.Add. Set the FileName property on the returned RDOAttachment object.