# C# I want to attach a workbook to Outlook Email and preview before sending

Tags: c#, excel, outlook

I have a piece of code that creates a workbook from a datagridview. After clicking a button and without saving the file to disk, I want to be able to attach that workbook into outlook so I can then choose who to send it to.

This is the result I want to achieve:

[image: example 1]

However, when I run the code, the email opens but there is not attachment, only this error message:

[image: example 2]

This is my code:

```
private void attachEmail()
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
        Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        try
        {
            worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
            worksheet.Name = "Sheet1";
            for (int i = 0; i < mydataGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = mydataGridView.Columns[i].HeaderText;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < mydataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < mydataGridView.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = mydataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            mailItem.Subject = "Notification";
            mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
            mailItem.Display(false);
            mailItem.Attachments.Add(workbook);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            excel.Quit();
            workbook = null;
            excel = null;
        }
    }
```

**Edit with code Update**

I stumbled upon some code to retrieve the data from memory. I'm not exactly sure how it works (I'm new with coding), but it is doing something different, I guess close to what I'm trying to achieve (which is to attach a file to Outlook without saving it first):

```
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            workbook.SaveAs(stream);
            Byte[] bytearray = (Byte[])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(byte), stream.Length);
            stream.Position = 0;
            stream.Read(bytearray, 0, (int)stream.Length);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytearray);
            System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, "excelfile.xlsx");
            mailItem.Subject = "Notification";
            mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
            mailItem.Display(false);
            mailItem.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            stream.Close();
```

Unfortunately I'm getting a very vague error:

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8YGR.png)

Comment: I am pretty sure workbook variable is null during attachment time. Check to see if it is null right before you attach it in mailItem.Attachments.Add(workbook);, and troubleshoot it from there. It may be as something as simple as a permissions issue. Even try running this script as an elevated privilege account to mitigate that case.

Comment: I used "workbook.SendMail("myemail@email.com");" to test if there was something in the workbook. I've got the file emailed no problem. The issue is that I want to preview the email before I send.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071261/programmatically-attach-pdf-from-memorystream-to-outlook-e-mail-items

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to save and close the workbook, and use the filename as the attachment.  I tested this, and it does produce the outcome you seek:

```
workbook.SaveAs(@"c:\cdh\foo.xlsx");
workbook.Close();

mailItem.Subject = "Notification";
mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
mailItem.Display(false);
mailItem.Attachments.Add(@"c:\cdh\foo.xlsx");
```

Comment: Thank you Hambone for the answer. Like I mentioned on my question, I'm trying to attach the file to email without saving the file to disk. I've seeing it in other programs so I'm sure there should be a way to achieve it.

Comment: Aah, okay.  I missed that part.

Comment: I edited the original question to include some "bytearray" code that I found. Would you mind taking a look at it?

Comment: @Pucho -- take a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/156524/1278553.  It seems there may be third party libraries that do this, but I don't know of a way to do this via Interop.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that. It sucks that interop lets you send an excel file straight to an email recipient (myworkbook.SendMail("recipient@email.com"))but it doesn't let you preview it before sending. I wonder how the apps I've seen do it.

Comment: My guess is if the VBA library support it, Interop does also, and if it doesn't...  What about saving it as a temp file (in %TEMP%)?

Comment: There is no way to avoid IO and manipulate Office files in-memory.  The only way is to avoid Interops and manipulate at lower level using C++ but that's a rabbit hole as there's very little documentation.  Easiest way is to use recommended IO route.

Answer (score 0):

Resurrected thread:

```
excel.Dialogs[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogSendMail].Show();
```